# Combining queries in nested react-router-relay routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, relay, react-router-relay

I have a schema with a `viewer` as topmost root element and all other data under it: the `viewer` has a list of `users` and supplies a single `user(id)`. There is no other element in my root query.

My root component has defined following routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)} environment={Relay.Store}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="users" component={UserList} queries={ViewerQueries}>
            <Route path=":userId" component={UserDetails} queries={UserQueries} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

These are the queries - I don't know how to make `UserQueries` to be nested within `ViewerQueries` or if this is even possible:

```
const ViewerQueries = {
  viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }`
};

const UserQueries = {
  user: () => Relay.QL`query { user(id: $userId) }`
}
```

My goal for the `UserDetails` component is to get its data from

```
query {
  viewer {
    user(id: "xyz") {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I get the following error when trying this:

```
Error: Cannot query field "user" on type "RootQuery".
```

How do I teach react-router-relay to let `UserDetails` get it's data from

`query { viewer { user(id) } }`

and not just from

`query { user(id) }`?